# Hide overflow of div on edges

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow, styling

I got an main div called `outerdiv` with a div-element inside called `innerdiv`.

Because the `outerdiv` got the `"border-radius"` attribute and so the `innerdiv` conceals the nice edges of the `outerdiv`.

<> I hope you could get what I mean. But have a look at the code:

```css
#outerdiv {
  position: fixed; 
  width: 80%; 
  left: 50%; 
  margin-left: -40%;     
  height: 30%; 
  background: red; 
  margin-top: 5%; 
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px
}

#innerdiv {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  height: 40%;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover="document.getElementById('innerdiv').style.display='none'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('innerdiv').style.display=''" id="outerdiv">
  <div id="innerdiv"></div>
</div>


<p style="position: fixed; top: 50%">>MOVE YOUR MOUSE POINTER OVER THE RED AREA TO GET WHAT I MEAN.</p>
```

To my question: How can I make the overflow of the `innerdiv` hidden to don't let it cover up the nice edges of the `outerdiv`.

Note:  *(The simplest solution)* - Just adding the same `border-radius` attribute to the `innerdiv` is NO SOLUTION IN THIS CASE.

What I've tried to add is the attribute `overflow` but it doesn't seems working this way:

```
#innerdiv {
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

> Edit: I'd like the green element to not display above the red corners.

Comment: why are the answers downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`overflow: hidden` does work, you need to apply it on your `#outerdiv`, not the `#innerdiv`.

```css
#outerdiv {
  position: fixed; 
  width: 80%; 
  left: 50%; 
  margin-left: -40%;     
  height: 30%; 
  background: red; 
  margin-top: 5%; 
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#innerdiv {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  height: 40%;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerdiv">
  <div id="innerdiv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)